# using select and stringr together

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I'm trying

```
qual %>% select(reasons_code) %>% str_replace('\\+.*',replacement = '')
```

but I get the Warning message: In stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement), : argument is not an atomic vector; coercing.

However, when I do the following, the replacement works fine.

```
str_replace(qual$reasons_code,'\\+.*',replacement = '')
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Try `qual %>% pull(reasons_code) %>% str_replace('\\+.*',replacement = '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `?str_replace`, the input `string` is

> string - Input vector. Either a character vector, or something coercible to one.

while, the output from `select` is a `data.frame` with a single column selected.  It is not converted to `vector`.  Instead of `select`, we can `pull` the column as `vector` and it should work

```
library(dplyr)
qual %>%
      pull(reasons_code) %>%
      str_replace('\\+.*',replacement = '')
```

Or if we prefer to use the OP's code with `select`, there are several ways to convert to `vector` - `unlist` is one of them

```
qual %>% 
    select(reasons_code) %>% 
    unlist %>%
    str_replace('\\+.*',replacement = '')
```